# how to add intent when click any image on Carousel adapter?

Tags: android

I have an 3d CarouselAdapter which displays images. How can I add an intent method in this code so that when an image is clicked an Activity opens? I am following the following tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Answer (score 0):

`Carousel` is one Custom View like Gallery and it has a Custom Adapter Class called `CarouselAdapter`. So just implements `OnItemClickListener` to Carousel.

Yeah, do like this,

```
Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {    

// Your Activity starting code goes here...

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("%s has been clicked",((CarouselItem)parent.getChildAt(position)).getName()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
  }         
});
```

Comment: i didnot define carosel in main

Comment: plz help me iwant to add same pages in this code so when i click any iamge i go diffrent screen how it is possible???

Comment: You have to define `Carousel` in activity and then implement `OnItemClick...` to it.

Comment: it ry it so many error will come plz just add some pages in this code and called them by clicking image  and send me that code on  nazeerahmed24@hotmail.com  plzzz